# Extension of Ramsey's Theorem to 100 people

Tags: ramsey-theory

A group of 100 knights arrived at a tournament. Each knight knew at least 67 other knights. Show that there exists 4 knights that mutually know each other.

I know how to prove small amounts of people with a diagram by drawing lines to each other person and coloring them to represent do/don't know, but I obviously can't draw a diagram for this.

Comment: Each knight knows 67 of the 99 others, so there are at most 32 whom he doesn't know. Choose one knight A, and let a dragon eat all those whom he doesn't know (at most 32). So A knows all the survivors. Now choose one of the survivors B, and let the dragon also eat those whom B doesn't know. So at most 64 have been eaten, leaving A, B, and at least 34 others whom A and B both know. Let C be one of those 34, and let the dragon eat all whom C doesn't know. Of the 34, one is C, at most 32 get eaten, so at least one survives; call him D. Then A,B,C,D all know each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take one knight, Sir Arthur. He has at least $67$ friends, so we can take one of them, who is called Sir Loin of Beef.

Of the remaining $98$, Sir Arthur known at least $66$, and so does Sir Beef. Therefore the overlap between their circles of aquaintances has to be at least $34$. From those $34$, pick one and call him Sir Cumference.

Of the remaining $97$ knights, at least $33$ are mutual aquaintances of Sir Arthur and Sir Beef, while at least $65$ are known to Sir Cumference. Those two groups must overlap by at least one knight, say Sir Duke.

The knights Sir Arthur, Sir Beef, Sir Cumference and Sir Duke all know each other.

Comment: Bugs Bunny yields the delayed Sir Loin of **B**eef.  But I understand if that's not suitable.

Comment: @BrianTung I like it.

Comment: I dont understand how this is off topic...

Comment: @GerardL. I think it's this part: "Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it." The only thing you've said is that you obviously can't draw a diagram. Some people want more than that.